# ConTeXt mkiv bibliography and chicago style

Tags: bibliographies, context

Between the three bibliography-setting commands of Context mkiv, what is the hierarchy?

```
\usebtxdefinitions[aps]
\definebtxrendering[default][chicago][specification=chicago,sorttype=authoryear,numbering=no]
\setupbtxlist[chicago][]
```

If the only thing I need is chicago, and use \usebtxdefinitions[chicago], I get a blank bibliography with `<article>` instead of the citation, although chicago is mentioned among the basic styles. So  I use it as written and it works OK, but I just want to understand the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `chicago` style yet.  The only available styles are `apa` and `aps` and there is an [experimental `ieee` style by Aditya](https://gist.github.com/adityam/afda949f76676055e7906679599ec937).  If you read the [documentation](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf) carefully you'll find (emphasis mine):

> Alternatives to `specification=apa` **might be** `mla`, `chicago`, `harvard`, `ieee`, `aps` (commonly used in the physical sciences), `vancouver` (used in the biological sciences), or many others.

You can also see it from the definition of `\setupbtx` that there only exist `default`, `apa`, and `aps`.  The all caps `NAME` is only a placeholder for any other user-defined instance.

[image]

Also, don't be fooled by the names `apa` and `aps`.  Even though there are proper specifications for an APA and an APS style out there, `apa` is only a generic author-year style and `aps` a generic numbered style, which are loosely based on the actual specifications.

Comment: I have noticed apa and aps do all I want, actually. So if there is no chicago style for the time being, the package works well anyway (I use ConTeXtstandalone), so I will manage. :) \footnote{\cite[entry][key]} actually does miracles, this function is really important.

Comment: @DmitryStarostin, what "miracle" does `\footnote{\cite[entry][key]` do? (I still don't get the [key] part.) By the way, the `chicago` style is available now.