# How to set BibTeX to display Chicago style in ConTeXt?

Tags: bibtex, citing, context

I heard that ConTeXt was updated to include Chicago style, so I tried this code:

```
 \setuppapersize[A4]

 \startbuffer [bib]
 @Book{ball1996,
  author = {Ball, Larry},
  title = {Desert lawmen: the high sheriffs of New Mexico and Arizona, 1846-1912},
  publisher = {University of New Mexico Press},
 year = {1996},
 address = {Albuquerque},
 isbn = {9780826317001}
 }
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[bib.buffer]

\usebtxdefinitions [chicago] 

\setupbtx
[chicago]

\starttext

This is text\cite[ball1996] and more text.

\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

Unfortunately, this looks like APA, not Chicago.

I located the file `tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/publ-imp-chicago.mkvi` in my system, so it seems it should know Chicago style. And when I compile, I see it is accessing that file...

```
open source     > level 2, order 3, name '/home/username/.context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/publ-imp-chicago.mkvi'
close source    > level 2, order 3, name '/home/username/.context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/publ-imp-chicago.mkvi'
```

...so why isn't it working? What is the correct way to turn on Chicago style in ConTeXt?

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474537/117125

Comment: I have heard that there is now a Chicao style available.

Comment: @DaveJarvis It compiles without error, but appears to continue using APA style citations.

Comment: ask on the context mailing list. They will know how faithfully a style has been implemented.

Comment: Perhaps it only supports Chicago author-date style and not note style?

Comment: @DavidPurton That might be what is happening! I had no idea there was such a thing as Chicago author-date style, I use Turabian's book, and wrote in History, where we use footnotes...thought that *was* Chicago. I guess I will continue trying to recreate Chicago from scratch.

Comment: It is an imperfect implementation of Chicago author-date style. There is no footnote-based bibliography style yet for ConTeXt, to my knowledge.